# Deploy static HTML javadoc pages in a jar file on server

Tags: deployment, jar, webserver, javadoc

I have a jar file with generated static javadoc pages.
How can I deploy it on a server and which URL should I use to call the index.html on my webserver.

Supposed:

myAppJavadoc.jar is the javadoc jar file

the link

server-url/myAppJavadoc/index.html doesn't work.

Do I have to configure the entryPoint for the jar via javadoc option? Or do I have to deploy it as exploded files on the webserver?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

I found my own answer.
Somehow I missed the point before my post, sorry.

You have to rename the .jar file in .war, deploy it in your webserver in the deployment directory and call it in the above described way:
server-url/myAppJavadoc/index.html works fine if it is a .war file.